# Acronis TrueImage .TIB file conversion to .VHD

Tags: windows, backup-restoration, disk-image

I've made several backups of older 2000 and XP machines I've phased out over the last year or so.

These were done with 'Seagate DiskWizard' from Hiren's Boot CD (Acronis True Image Home (v9.5 I think)) and produced .tib files which I've archived and kept.

One of my users (several months later) decides she is missing some internet favourites and program settings from her old install (or has removed them since my migration and wants them back).

I have downloaded a trial of 'Acronis Backup & Recovery 11.5' with the intensions of converting the .tib files to .vhd and booting them when required (probably with Windows Virtual PC).

[Several](http://forum.acronis.com/forum/33761) places on the Acronis site mention converting easily, but I'm unable to see the option in B&R 11.5. Going a [different route](http://kb.acronis.com/content/3499), B&R 11.5 does not identify the .tib files I have when pointed at the location, reporting 'There are no items to show in this view.' for both 'Data' and 'Archive' views in the Recovery 'Data Selection'.

Any pointers?

Comment: Note: I am using both solutions from the below answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternate method would be to use the [VMware vCenter Converter Standalone 5](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/info/slug/infrastructure_operations_management/vmware_vcenter_converter_standalone/5_0) to convert the tib image into a vmdk and then convert that into a vhd using the [StarWind V2V converter](http://www.starwindsoftware.com/converter).

Comment: Does that read older-versions of tib files?  (honestly curious... trying to avoid installing it to find out that it doesn't.)

Comment: --to answer my own question: from the manual:  "Acronis True Image Echo 9.1, 9.5, and Acronis True Image Home 10 and 11 (.tib)."

Comment: These are the supported Acronis soure machine versions: Acronis True Image Echo 9.1, 9.5, and Acronis True Image Home 10 and 11

Comment: It has read the older files and converted them for me... Note to self: don't use a 80gb .tib file as a test! I'm probably going to use a combination of this to convert some VM's (the smaller) and then @TheCompWiz's answer above for the larger as it'll be quicker...

Answer (score 3):

I've actually run into a very similar problem.  There's a few gotchyas with acronis which drive me nuts.  First, images in older versions don't always work in newer versions.  Second, each version has a slightly different structure, so manually trying to rip them apart and piece them back together is a nightmare.

Your best bet, is to create a virtual HD, and boot off of the live-CD you used to create the image, and then restore the image from a thumb-drive to that VHD.

Comment: (just be glad it wasn't a linux image in a software RAID.  Acronis doesn't bother backing up the metadata for the RAID.)

Comment: Ouch! One of the many reasons to go careful with software RAID's... I'm going to get away from Acronis as i'd heard of .tib related problems before... The liveCD 'restore' is sounding like the best option and then just create my .vhd's from there, but it takes much more work (& time!) grr! :)

Comment: Luckily... linux isn't dumb.  I just had to tell grub which disk to use and pass `boot=/dev/sda1` as a kernel parameter.   YEAH LINUX!